# how to loop through the range of \u2190-\u21FF in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I want to know  \u2190-\u21FF what is that?

how to loop through the range of  \u2190-\u21FF in python2?

unicode  \u2190-\u21FF

my only be parsed \u0030-\u0039

```
for i in range(0x30,0x38):
    print chr(i)
# 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

parsing \u2190-\u21FF is not supported

and How to calculate the hexadecimal of 0039?

```
print hex(0039)
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
>>> for i in range(0x3000,0x303F):
...     print unichr(i)
... 
　
、
。
〃
〄
々
〆
〇
〈
〉
《
》
「
」
『
』
【
】
〒
〓
〔
〕
〖
〗
〘
〙
```

and `0039` has leading zero, which makes it an `octal` constant, hence the number `9` is forbidden there. Please, make sure you're converting correct numbers.

Comment: I just knew, you answered

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly with Python 3.6

**Edit**: I added the `Python 2.7` tag to the original question

```
for i in range(0x3000,0x303F):
    print (chr(i))
```

The `print hex(0039)` problem is trickier

Python do not accept a literal integer with leading 0. But it can convert a string with leading 0 to integer.

This means that you are simply not allowed to write `hex(0039)` or even `int(0039)` but why would you? `hex(39)`works just fine.

And if you deal with string, there is no problem as long as you convert it as `int`

```
s = '0039'
print  (hex(int(s)))
```

Comment: @xin.chen I added the apriopriate flag, then. I have no python 2 installed